# beginner's questoin: How to Compile ROS PKG?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all

I have followed all the beginner's tutorial from ROS webpage. I still have trouble understanding the precise procedure of compiling a pkg, obtained from a website.
In my particular interest is : https://github.com/segwayrmp/segway-rmp-ros-pkg,
after download it. I did:

1.Rosmake [package_name]
2.Roscd to [package_name]
3.make

Are these the correct steps in compiling packages like this?
why Makefile is missing from the top level of the package?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63345/beginner%27s-questoin:-how-to-compile-ros-pkg?/) by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 146 on 2013-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are two build systems in ROS: `rosbuild` - the original one and `catkin`- the newer one. The package you are referring to uses catkin.

Instructions for compiling catkin packages can also be found in the tutorials. There should be a button at the top in the tutorials where you can switch between rosbuild and catkin.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on 2013-05-23**:
ok. I see. I was told to use rosbuild, not catkin.  Thank you, I now go and explore the catkin version. But
as for the rosbuild version, do you agree with the steps I took?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-05-24**:
rosmake package_name is sufficient. You can also still use rosbuild with your own code and depend on the catkin packages. Just for building a catkin package catkin is required.